# Makefile, conditional and wildcard with variables

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements, wildcard

I'm having troubles with my makefile. I want to have a "master" target which automatically processes a variety of dirs and copies them in a specific location. But somehow the ifneq condition with the wildcard is not working properly, giving me always the same result regardless of the condition being satisfied or not.

I'm trying with:

```
# Basically the same thing for all targets
% :
ifeq ($(wildcard $(TOP)/flow/$@),)
    $(error Directory $(TOP)/flow/$@ not found. Aborting. Debug: $(wildcard $(TOP)/flow/$@))
else
    $(error Directory $(TOP)/flow/$@ found!. Debug: $(wildcard $(TOP)/flow/$@))
endif
```

As an example, in $(TOP)/flow exists a directory **core** but not **pwr**. The Make target proceed as if they both exist.

```
➜  work ✗ make core
Makefile:20: *** Directory TOPFOLDER/flow/core found!. Debug: TOPFOLDER/flow/core.  Stop.
➜  work ✗ make pwr 
Makefile:20: *** Directory TOPFOLDER/flow/pwr found!. Debug: .  Stop.
```

Why is this so? Can't see what I'm doing wrong here.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: That's pretty dense. I think I know what the source of the error is, but could you explain a little more clearly what you want this makefile to *do?*

Comment: I rewrote the question with a simpler use case which fails nonetheless. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$@` is empty at the time the `ifeq` is evaluated.

Probably use a run-time check instead:

```
% :
    test -d $(TOP)/flow/$@/
```